# Insert a string by condition in R

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements, gsub

I have this situation, but with much more information:

```
Barcode
NM00000512
NM000522
NM00000513
NM000514
```

And I would like to insert two more zeros in the shorter Barcodes, like this:

```
Barcode
NM00000512
NM00000522
NM00000513
NM00000514
```

I tried this `df$Barcode <- gsub('NM000', "NM00000",df$Barcode)` but didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight modification of the original attempt: instead of replacing all `NM000` replace `NM000` only if it is followed by a character that is not 0 `[^0]` but make sure to capture it `()` and put it back in with `\\1`.

```
df$Barcode <- gsub('NM000([^0])', "NM00000\\1",df$Barcode)

> df
#      Barcode
# 1 NM00000512
# 2 NM00000522
# 3 NM00000513
# 4 NM00000514
```

Alternatively using the same idea and *negative lookahead*:

```
gsub('NM000(?!=0)', "NM00000", df$Barcode, perl = TRUE)
```

Reproducible data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Barcode = c("NM00000512", "NM000522", "NM00000513", "NM000514"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Other answers make assumptions about the number of zeros (that there should be five). I assume that there should be exactly two characters in the front. If that's not the case, you could modify it to split the string before the first numeric digit (or according to whatever different rule applies).

```
barcode <- c("NM00000512", "NM000522", "NM00000513", "NM000514")


pad <- function(barcode) {
  x <- as.integer(substring(barcode, 3)) #extract numbers
  n <- max(nchar(barcode)) - 2 #desired length of number in string
  paste0(substring(barcode, 1, 2), #the two characters
         sprintf(paste0("%0", n, "i"), x) #pad with zeros
         )
}

pad(barcode)
#[1] "NM00000512" "NM00000522" "NM00000513" "NM00000514"
```

Comment: Following your idea and @sindri_baldur answer, `gsub('(.*?)[^0]0+(.*)', "\\100000\\2",df$Barcode)` is shorter and assumes even less.

Answer (score 4):

We can replace all the 0's in the string with 5 0's

```
sub("0+", "00000", df$Barcode)
#[1] "NM00000512" "NM00000522" "NM00000513" "NM00000514"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
x <- c("NM00000512","NM000522","NM00000513","NM000514")
library(stringr)
str_replace(x, "(?<=^NM)\\d+$", function(x) str_pad(x, 8, side = "left", pad = "0"))
## => [1] "NM00000512" "NM00000522" "NM00000513" "NM00000514"
```

If there can be up to 8 digits from `NM` till the end of string use

```
str_replace(x, "(?<=^NM)\\d{1,8}$", function(x) str_pad(x, 8, side = "left", pad = "0"))
##                         ^^^^^
```

**Details**

- `(?<=^NM)` - matches a place immediately preceded with `NM` at the start of a string
- `\d{1,8}` - 1 to 8 digits (`\d+` matches 1+ digits)
- `$` - end of string

The `str_pad(x, 8, side = "left", pad = "0")` pads the matched number with zeros on the left.